# Java Swing layout that depends on children?

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm looking for a straightforward way of handling the following:

All items of type A should be laid out horizontally.
All items of type B should be laid out vertically. So, for example:

```
AAA
B
AA
B
B
AAAAAA
```

The type B items will be containers with this same behavior so the whole thing will nest any number of levels deep.

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this without putting a container around the collections of A's?

Comment: Does the number of A's and B's determinable ?

Comment: Why "without putting a container around the collections of A's"? Usually, when faced with any non-trivial problem, I really like to reduce it to one or more simpler problems. In this case putting a container around the A's reduces it to a combination of simple vertical and horizontal layouts, which seems to me to be a good thing. What is the motivation for not doing that reduction?

Comment: Use a combination of compound components/layouts.  Basically you could use a simple `GridLayout` (which has already been suggested) for the base layout, using a single column.  Add each row of "A" to a `JPanel` using something like `FlowLayout` and each "B" could be added directly to the parent container or a child container if you need additional layout assistance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search a bit you will find a VerticalFlowLayout. As I see what you need is a custom layout manager, because you have to deal with FlowLayout and VarticalFlowLayout mixing.

You have to override / implement the basic methods: [described here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html)

I would store the data in two dimension array / list as Rows and Columns.
Overriding the addLayoutComponent and removeLayoutComponent is a must.

I hope it helps!

Comment: That is the "without putting a container around the collections of A's" part in my question. I'm asking if there is some way to avoid having to surround the horizontal containers around the A elements.

Comment: @taotree yes,  "As I see what you need is a custom layout manager, because" So, once again: I am suggesting to do a custom LayoutManager. Take the source code from VerticalFlowLayout and the FlowLayout ( horizontal) and do the custom logic mixed where you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GridLayout` to arrange A's in it's rows and B's in it's columns .

Comment: +1, it will be a bit hard to handle the left, right alignment and when not all A is the same length in each row, it is a bit ugly interface or code :) but it could be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

add A's to a JPanel (GridLayout(1,0))

add B's to a JPanel (GridLayout(0,1))

add each A and B panel to a holdingPanel (BoxLayout(Y_AXIS))